# DSHOME not found in Datastage

Tags: datastage

i want to run a job from putty, when I use DSjob the message, not found I tried to find the DSHOME also it is return not found? can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to source the dsenv file first - this will set the necessary paths.
Go to you Infosphere installation directory and run

```
. ./dsenv
```

You can also add it to the .profile of your user so it gets set automatically at login time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can someone help me to install it? Because I tried to find the solution in Google I tried a lot of solution

Comment: What do you mean with install? You have to run dsjob on the InfoShere Server -  which should be installed otherwise I do not understand your first question. Search for dsenv and change to that directory